# how to run TimerTask off main UI thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am having trouble with a TimerTask Interfering with In App Purchasing (Async Tasks).
I am weak with Threads, so I believe it is running on the main UI thread, eating up resources.
How can I run this outside the UI thread? I have searched, and tried some suggestions using handlers. but seems like I get the same result, app gets really laggy.
when I don't run this task (refreshes every 500mS), the activity runs smoothly, and there are no hangs during In app purchases.
Your help is appreciated, code snippet below:

public class DummyButtonClickerActivity extends Activity {

```
        protected Timer timeTicker = new Timer("Ticker");
        private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
        protected int timeTickDown = 20;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainhd);

    // start money earned timer handler
    TimerTask tick = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            myTickTask();
        }
    }; 

    timeTicker.scheduleAtFixedRate(tick, 0, 500); // 500 ms each


} // End OnCreate



protected void myTickTask() {

    if (timeTickDown == 0) {

        /// run my code here
        //total = total + _Rate;





        timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout);
}
      else if(timeTickDown < 0) {
        // do nothing
    }

    timeTickDown--;

}

private Runnable doUpdateTimeout = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        updateTimeout();
    }
};



private void updateTimeout() {

    // reset tick
    timeTickDown = 2; // 2* 500ms == once a second



}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have to run every half second?? Rethink the design.

Comment: Please indent your code properly, as it is very difficult to read as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HandlerThread` that will run your Handler on a separate Thread

**documentation:**

```
 Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper.
 The looper can then be used to create handler classes. Note that start() must still be called.
```

**example:**

```
     HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("my-handler");
     mHandlerThread.start();
     Handler mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

update:

```
 private Runnable doUpdateTimeout;
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private Handler timerHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainhd);

    // start money earned timer handler
    TimerTask tick = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            myTickTask();
        }
    }; 

    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("my-handler");
    mHandlerThread.start();

    timerHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
    doUpdateTimeout = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            updateTimeout();
        }
    };

    timeTicker.scheduleAtFixedRate(tick, 0, 500); // 500 ms each


} // End OnCreate



protected void myTickTask() {

    if (timeTickDown == 0) {

        /// run my code here
        //total = total + _Rate;

        timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout);
}
      else if(timeTickDown < 0) {
        // do nothing
    }

    timeTickDown--;

}





private void updateTimeout() {

    // reset tick
    timeTickDown = 2; // 2* 500ms == once a second

}
}
```

when you want to update the TextView from different thread

**call this:**

```
YOU_ACITIVITY_CLASS.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //update here

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still not sure how to continue from here?

Comment: How do use my code , now that these handlers/handlerThread? Sorry, I am very new to this.Thanks

Comment: sorry meant, now that these handlers/threads are defined and started?

Comment: Thanks for the update code, but it doesnt seem to like this:                 doUpdateTimeout = new Runnable(mHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
        public void run() {                                             The constructor Object(HandlerThread) is 
  undefined?

Comment: I have this imported                                                   import android.os.HandlerThread;

Comment: looks like Im trying to pass a HandlerThread in a Runnable? is that allowed?

Comment: @huskyd97 answer edditted sorry it is supposed to be the handler not the runnable

Comment: Thanks Rod_Algonquin. I corrected that. but still having trouble updating textview from this, since now I am running outside of the UI thread.

Comment: @huskyd97 if you want to updatate the UI(textView) from a thread you should call the runonUIthread. EDITTED

Answer (score 0):

The handler is running and processing in the main ui thread,so the  method `doUpdateTimeout` will be executed in the main thread.

In your code, after running 10 seconds later,the `timeTickDown` equals to 0 and code `timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout);` will be invoked,which will be executed in the main thread. Because it just let `timeTickDown = 2;` one second later,this code will be executed again(in the main ui thread) and then go on in each second.If there is some other code in `doUpdateTimeout` or `updateTimeout`,your main thread will be laggy.

Just change `timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout);` to `updateTimeout()`(call it directly and then execute it in the `Timer` thread,not the main ui thread).

Comment: Still a bit confused, I have this in my code so far, but does not loop.

Comment: HandlerThread moneyEarnHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("moneyearn-handler");
      moneyEarnHandlerThread.start();
      moneyearnedHandler = new Handler(moneyEarnHandlerThread.getLooper());
      moneyearnedHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override 
             public void run() { 
              myTickTask();
              
             }
      });                                                     
 } // end main

Comment: protected void myTickTask() {

  if (timeTickDown == 0) {

   /// run my code here
   //total = total + _Rate;

   
    
    
   
   //timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout); <--commented out per your suggestion
   updateTimeout(); // <--added this
    }
          else if(timeTickDown < 0) {
   // do nothing
  }

  timeTickDown--;

 }

 private Runnable doUpdateTimeout = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

   updateTimeout();
  }
 };

   

 private void updateTimeout() {

  // reset tick
  timeTickDown = 2; // 2* 500ms == once a second

  

 }

Comment: @huskyd97 I don´t think using HandlerThread is the solution to this question,because the Timer has its own thread,no need to use HandlerThread to make this.The key to your problem is the runnable that posted to your main ui thread by code timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout);

Comment: thanks. so is there anyway I can make this work, with current code? basically how to avoid running timerHandler.post(doUpdateTimeout) in main UI thread? I have tried a few scenarios without success.

Comment: Just change it to  updateTimeout(); call it directly and then it will be executed in the timer's thread.

Comment: Ok, so looks like its running off main thread now, only problem is during each update or refresh, I need to update a textview defined in my main xml. it errors at this step. the textview is called below                                  private void updateTimeout() {

  timeTickDown = 2; // 2* 500ms == once a second

  diff = total - start;
  
   earnratetext.setText("$ " + diff");

Comment: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: seems you have other  code that will operate the view in method updateTime，because this operation must be done in the main ui thread，your question can not be resolved。I think you  reduce the interval.